# Read values from UITextfield's on UIView which is added as Contentview UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to show editable fields similar like Employee.

EmpName   EmpTitle  EmpDOB   EmpHobby

for suppose 20 employee. suppose all fields are editable.

I have created `UIView` and added all `UITextField` for EmpName ETC.

I am adding that `UIView` to `cell.contentView`

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:[self displayEmpView]];
```

This gives me perfect design, to show for 20 Employee repeated design.

Now my problem is how can i access `UITextField` Values. `UITextField` are on `UIView` which is added as content view. I need to save back change values.

Is this possible? or is there any better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement delegate methods for `UITextField` which will respond to all text events. Make your class conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`

You can loop through all subviews in your `cell.contentView` and find the subviews which are of kind `UITextField` , and set `yourTextfield.delegate=self;`

To save the data from all the rows:

```
-(IBAction)save{

   for(int i=0;i<rowCont;i++){
    UITableViewCell *cell = [mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
      for(UITextField *txtField in cell.contentView.subviews){
     NSString *text = [txtField text];
        //save the value of text
     }
   }
```

This could be the ugly way of doing it, but to make things more easier and cleaner, you could maintain a dictionary and append textField values to the dictionary each time you finish entering the values into textfield.
So the delegate method textFieldDidEndEditing would get called when you move onto another textField, so you could do

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField * ) textField
{
    //Store the textField.text in the dictionary here
}
```

SO at the end you will have a dictionary with all the 20 values, and you can simply save this dictionary on button click to wherevr you want.

Comment: uiview has 6 uitexfield, and for 20 row of uitableview i am adding same uiview......plz note i am not adding uitextfields directly to cell...

Comment: It's ok. Set the delegate of all textfields before you add your view to contentView

Comment: ok then how can i read values..... like on save button click i need to suppose read values from all rows...then

Comment: you cannot enter values into 20 rows one by one and save it at the end, as rows get scrolled they will be reused and your data gets lost if you don't persist it! @user2813740

Comment: i am not using nil for cell.... my data will remain... but taken in to consideration only 5 rows....then

Comment: i do not want to change design as..it is perfect for requirement.... after doing almost everything while saving i am stuck.... i can send array of nsdictionary. where as easy dictionary will have values from each row.   so i will read textfield values from ROW 0 and add dictionary to array and so on....

Comment: i will check but as i mention i am not directly adding uitextfield as contentView.subviews to cell.  instead my all uitextfield are on UIView.... and i am adding uiview as contentView.subviews to cell.....

Comment: yes your textFieldDidEndEditing, just put light in my head.... i can see selected cell row..and save values in dictionary and replace that reticular index item inside ARRAY.  thinking too much...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:[self displayEmpView]];
displayEmView.tg = indexPath.row+1000;
UITextFiele1.tag = indexPath.row+1001;
```

and so on...

when you need to use do this:

```
UIView * displayEmpView = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row+1000];
UITexField *txtFieldABC = [displayEmpView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+1001];
```

But i prefer not using it, let create you custom UITableViewCell and make an outLet for all of your UI components.